# Как удалить файлы в git

Tags: bitbucket, git

Работаю с git, уже какой раз выходит вот такое уведомление:

[image: img]

Как удалить эти ненужные файлы?

Comment: git rm - не помогает?

Comment: вы после того как удалили файлы включили это изменение в коммит?

Comment: @zhenyab не помогает :(

Comment: а в какой момент Вы получаете это уведомление?

Comment: `git add .`  это то что нужно

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать с помощью команды `git add -u`, которая индексирует все удаленные и все измененные файлы:

```
 git add -u
 git commit -m "Commit text"
```

Есть вариант `git add --all`, который индексирует все удаленные + все измененные + все ранее не отслеживаемые.

Comment: Единственное правильное решение будет.

У него в коде и удаление файлов было и добавление и тут нужно выполнить все операции.

Comment: @Shrek именно, после этого комита и файлы из хранилища удалились :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, может отдельным ответом напишешь?

Comment: @Qwertiy я считаю, что было необходимо отредактировать именно этот, и вот почему: `--all` добавляет вообще все файлы, включая changed & unstaged. Если **явным** образом об этом не предупредить, то кто-нибудь может случайно закоммитить все изменения и дальше будет искать "Как отменить коммит, как разбить коммит на N штук и т.п."  Это как на "отменить изменения в файле" отвечают "просто сделай git reset --hard". Уже пару раз сталкивался с таким.